# How to load home page after refreshing or reloading in any view in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I have 3 views (login, chat and Map) in an AngularJS application. If I'm in Map View and clicked on refresh button my page must get redirect to chat view after refreshing page. Experts please suggest how to implement.

Answer (score 1):

very simple method I tried to implement.In test function I gave $rootScope.test=true; in chat view controller where as method called in Mapview. Whenever I reload my page value will get  be undefined and and gave if condition with

```
if($rootScope.test==undefined)
{
$location.path('/chat');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can implement you'r state navigation inside `beforeunload` browser event

```
var windowElement = angular.element($window);
windowElement.on('beforeunload', function (event) {
   // your code for state navigation 
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. Let me try to  implement  then will get back to you.